# Getting variable for X

Tags: jquery, variables, input, numbers

**>> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/Nxqxe/1/) <<**

So, this fiddle works as it should: when two radio's with a different `name` attribute are checked, text is shown which echoes the values of these buttons.

However, what if there are more radio's? I don't want to keep adding lines and vars for every `name` attribute.

I thought it might be possible to replace the names with values that end with numerals like such:

```
<input type="radio" name="score1" value="0"> 0
<input type="radio" name="score1" value="1"> 1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="score2" value="0"> 0
<input type="radio" name="score2" value="1"> 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="score3" value="0"> 0
<input type="radio" name="score3" value="1"> 1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="score4" value="0"> 0
<input type="radio" name="score4" value="1"> 1
```

This way, it should be possible to loop through the names and find the checked value for every `"input[name='score" + i + "']"` in which case is a natural number. When this value is known, it could be echoed with an `each` function. So, no matter how many radio buttons are available, the script always works (and shouldn't be too many lines).

Of course, this is how I see this in my head but I have no idea how one could really write a script like that. I'm not familiar with infinite number loops and the use of `i` and `ii`.

Interesting articles concerning this are welcome as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$( ":radio" ).on( "click", function () {
        var html = ""
        $(':radio :checked').each(function(){
            html += "<span>" + $(this).val() + "</span> - ";
        });
        $( "div#result" ).html(html).show();
});
```

Comment: This won't work because it doesn't takes in the name attributes and by doing so, it will just stack all values that have been clicked on, rather than one per row (i.e. name attribute).

Comment: @BramVanroy But for every `name` there can be only one radio that is `checked`. So printing out all the `checked` ones is equivalent to printing `checked` values for every `name`..

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry for being so skeptical. Thanks again!